# Getting the names of users with foreach

Tags: php

I want to recover the names returned by the query below (it's part of the code):

```
      while ($info = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
         foreach(array_chunk($info, 5) as $info){
echo ' <div class="user-block" style="display: inline-block;">

                     <h4>'.$info->name.'</h4>    
              </div> ';             
             }      
     }
```

But I get this:

> **Error**: Warning: array_chunk() expects parameter 1 to be array, object
>   given And that error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Check if the `$info` array is not empty

Comment: Change `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` to `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`

Comment: $info array is not empty And I have tried PDO::FETCH_ASSOC but i see "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object"

Answer (score 0):

Two possiblities:

a) Try using PDO::FETCH_ASSOC instead of PDO::FETCH_OBJ.  And change $info->name to $info['name']

b) You're only get 1 result from your query returned so it's not an array.  Remove the foreach loop

Comment: I have use  PDO::FETCH_ASSOC And $info['name'].  the error is  Notice: Undefined index: name in.   There are several elements to recover but I chose the name to do the tests first.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the array_chunk.  Assuming your query is something like "SELECT `name` from USERS"; try...
while ($info = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
echo ' <div class="user-block" style="display: inline-block;">

                     <h4>'.$info->name.'</h4>    
              </div> ';                 
     }

Comment: I want to display the name, the first name and the avatar by group of 5. That's why I use array_chunk

Comment: Do you mean that you only want to display 5 people at one time?  If so that should be in your query.   "SELECT * from USERS LIMIT 5".

while ($info = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
  echo $info->name;
}

Comment: I want to display in a div the name, the first name and the avatar by group of 5 to 5

Comment: Ahhh I see based on your second post.

$info is not an array, its a pointer.  Try  https://pastebin.com/gMfJ1fXP

edit: forgot to remove the last  } on the paste

Comment: I know it works without foreach,
but how then to display 5 element in a div after each request? I thought it's the function array_chunk () that can do that?

Comment: I have copy paste "pastebin.com/gMfJ1fXP ". Error: "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in". I have remove "}"

Comment: Your "while($info = ...)" is a pointer and one gets 1 user on each loop.  In order for your array_chunk to work $info needs to be an array of multiple users.  That's why I suggested....  https://pastebin.com/8RSiFq2H   It puts all of your users into an array so that your array_chunk can break them apart.

Comment: are you sure you don't want ->nom instead of ->name?

Comment: No I replaced ->name by ->nom but not working same error  "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in".

Answer (score 0):

I already used this:

```
    <?php  $listes_amis = liste_amis_commun_profil_clique();  ?>
    <?php foreach(array_chunk($listes_amis, 5) as $liste_amis):  ?>
      <div>
        <?php foreach($liste_amis as $liste_ami):  ?>
          <div class="user-block" style="display: inline-block;">
            <a href="voir_profil.php?id=<?php echo $liste_ami->id;?>"> 
                 <img  src="../members/<?php echo $liste_ami->id?>/avatar/<?php echo $liste_ami->avatar; ?> " style='margin:  3px; width: 150px; height: 150px;' class="img-circle" /> 
                 <h4 style="font-size: 20px; color: green; text-align: center; margin-top: -2px;" > <?php if(strlen($liste_ami->nom ."+".$liste_ami->prenom) > 15) echo substr($liste_ami->prenom,0,-10).'...'; else echo $liste_ami->prenom ." ".$liste_ami->nom; ?> </h4>
            </a>
          </div>           
        <?php endforeach ?> 
      </div>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

And it works well here